# Want to show current post number by total post in WordPress Infinite Scroll - Ajax Load More plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm using  WordPress Infinite Scroll - Ajax Load More plugin to load my post in search.php and i have to show results like this "Showing 6 of 7 results".

Ex:

I want to show like this “Showing 9 of 50 results” After clicking on load more button it will be “Showing 18 of 50 results” and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by using the repeater template and the almComplete callback function.

**Step 1: Repeater Template**

```
<article class="item" data-item="<?php echo $alm_item; ?>" data-total="<?php echo $alm_found_posts; ?>">
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p>Currently viewing item #<?php echo $alm_item; ?> of <?php echo $alm_found_posts; ?></p>
```

[image]

[image]

**Step 2: almComplete callback function**
For more details of almComplete callback function  [Link](https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/docs/callback-functions/)

```
window.almComplete = function(alm){
var container = document.querySelectorAll(“.alm-reveal”);
container = container[container.length-1]
var item = container.querySelector(‘.tf-item-for-t-post:last-child’);
var last = item.dataset.item;
var total = item.dataset.total;
document.getElementById(“alm-search-results-text”).innerHTML = “Showing ” + last + ” of ” + total + ” results”;

};
```